# What is the Discard Protocol actually used for?

Tags: ip, network-protocols

What is the Discard protocol used for?

Comment: [Really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discard_Protocol)?

Comment: No I'm just wasting my time on here. Of course really.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discard_Protocol :

> The Discard Protocol is the TCP/UDP equivalent of the Unix filesystem node /dev/null. Such a service is guaranteed to receive what is sent to it and can be used for debugging TCP and/or UDP code requiring a guaranteed reception of payload sent.